# Tensorflow: How to use 1D/2D operator on 4D data format like (batch_size, width, hight, channels) ,keep the batch_size and channels

Tags: python, tensorflow

Anything similar or any tutorial about this is thankful. If there is not a common way to solve this and I need to design a unique way for each operator just let me know. Cause I am really new to this. THANKS!!

using `tf.reduce_max()`on my data `data = (2,480,640,3)`, means `(batch_size, width, hight, channels)`, expect result like `(2,1,3)`, means find a max for each batch on each channel.

Something like the following pseudo code

```
for i, j in zip(batch_size, channels)
    img = data(i,:,:,j)    
    img_re = tf.reshape(img, shape=(480*640,))
    max = tf.reduce_max(img_re)
```

Also **2D** OP for each batch for each channel and output`(2,1,3)`
Please help.

Comment: `tf.unique` returns unique element in 1D tensor, and the result `y`length may be any integer greater than 0. So what does `1` in `(2,1,3)` mean? Generally speaking, we can use `tf.map_fn` to wrap 1D/2D operations. But `tf.unique` will return a variable length result. Tensorflow doesn't support variable length tensors. You have to make sure that every batch and every channel returns the same length. Or do you just want to get `idx` of `tf.unique`?

Comment: @giser_yuyang, hi you again:D Thank you, I redit it. I want perform my operator on specific slic. Is this question proper? Cause I google this topic, I get nothing related.

Comment: See you again. You can use `tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_max(data,axis=[1,2]),axis=1)` directly to get the desired results. But I guess you really know how to use `tf.map_fn` to wrap 1D/2D operations.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned that lots of api can operate on 4D data directly, as long as you set `axis` as an argument(if it is legal in **document**).

So **there is no** general way to expand my current 1D/2D operation. I have to recode to find a vectorized way, because of efficient.

for batch:

`tf.map_fn` can process the same operation for each tensor in a batch repeatly. [Here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) But it will generally **slower** than the vectorized way. Multi-input [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151482/tensorflow-how-to-use-tf-map-fn-to-process-two-input-tensor-shape-of-40-30-1)